# Variable is not defined inside a function

Tags: python

```
def Counter(Num):
    Num = str(Num)
    count = 0
    for i in Num:
        count = count + 1

def Reverse(Number):
    counter(Number)
    Number = str(Number)
    if Number[0] == Number[count]:
        print("The Original and The Reversed numbers are the same\n")
    else :
        print("The Original and the Reversed numbers aren't the same\n")
Reverse(123)
```

I am a beginner and I wanted to make a counter then use that counter to check if a number is same if reversed or not, but I always get (`name "count" is not defined`) error.

Comment: It looks like count is defined in your "Counter" function which is out of scope of the "Reverse" function

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback. Your claim of an error does not match the error in the code you posted.

Comment: `count` is defined in `Counter`. The function `Reverse` cannot get the variable `count`.

Comment: Did you mean: `if Number[0] == Number[-1]:`?

Comment: I called the function "Reverse" which is calling the function "Counter" , so how come variable "count" is not defined ?

Comment: I am purposely looking for the harder-non-obvious way to solve the problem so that i can learn , That's Why i didn't index using [-1]

Comment: See my comment to the answer by @BabanGain

Answer (score 1):

```
def Counter(Num):
    Num = str(Num)
    count = 0
    for i in Num:
        count = count + 1
    # count variable is local to Counter function. return the value get make it available from where it is being called
    return count

def Reverse(Number):
    count = Counter(Number)
    Number = str(Number)
    if Number[0] == Number[count-1]: # index starts from zero. last index is count-1.
        print("The Original and The Reversed numbers are the same\n")
    else :
        print("The Original and the Reversed numbers aren't the same\n")
Reverse(123)
```

It will not work for numbers having digits greater than 3 as it is checking only the first digit with the last digit.

Better Solution

```
def Reverse(Number):
     Number = str(Number)
     if Number == Number[::-1]:  # Number[::-1] reverses the string
         print("The Original and The Reversed numbers are the same\n")
     else :
        print("The Original and the Reversed numbers aren't the same\n")
```

Comment: You're right , but this isn't my complain, i just want to know why is count not defined even after calling it inside of a function

Comment: You don't `call` variables, you create them by assigning to them. They are then destroyed if created inside a function and the function exits. You can return their values as shown in this answer.

Comment: I didn't know that Variables get destroyed after the function ends, Is there a way to maintain a variable's value after calling a function ? Also Why should i avoid using globals?

Answer (score 0):

```
def Counter(Num):
Num = str(Num)
count=0
for i in Num:
    count = count + 1

def Reverse(Number):
    count=  Counter(Number)
    Number = str(Number)
    if Number[0] == Number[count-1]:
        print("The Original and The   Reversed numbers are the same\n")
    else :
        print("The Original and the Reversed numbers aren't the same\n")
Reverse(123)
```

You can define your variable as global, also do count-1 else your index goes out of range

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.